# How to cut a selection on Opencv images

Tags: python, opencv

Tell me how to cut the selected area in Opencv. At the moment, the area is highlighted and I want everything to be removed. White background.

Screenshot (https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVcUf.jpg)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread("57.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


th, threshed = cv2.threshold(gray, 100, 255, 
cv2.THRESH_OTSU|cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
morphed = cv2.morphologyEx(threshed, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, np.ones((2,2)))

cnts = cv2.findContours(morphed, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, 
cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE[-2]

nh, nw = img.shape[:2]
for cnt in cnts:
    x,y,w,h = bbox = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    if h < 0.4 * nh:
        continue
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 0, 255), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)

cv2.imshow("gray", img)
```

All that I could do, I tried to select the outlines of all the objects and delete everything less than the main text (you need to leave only 9 digits)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have the rectangles detected, you can fill in the rectangle with the white background and for that you must change the rectangle parameter (-1)

```
cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 255, 255), -1, cv2.LINE_AA)
```

Original image
[image]

An image detected with rectangles

[image]

An image with white background

[image]

My code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("numeros_romanos.jpg")
img = cv2.resize(img, (1024, 800), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

th, threshed = cv2.threshold(gray, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU|cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

im2, cnts, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(threshed, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, 
cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

for cnt in cnts:
    x,y,w,h = bbox = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 255, 255), -1, cv2.LINE_AA)

cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. And how to do the opposite so that your numbers remain that allocated, and the rest is removed.
598822517- leave the code (pure numbers) from the example